# restful route customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i customize restful route urls to friendly urls like stackoverflow ?

i have
stackoverflow.com/questions/424/

and i want to have
stackoverflow.com/questions/424/title-of-the-page

Comment: What is the "something-something" you're trying to do here? Provide some more details of your problem.

Comment: i changed something-something to title-of-the-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one controller you want to do this with, the simplest solution would probably be to add a route with an ignored parameter, like so:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.connect 'questions/:id/:ignored', :controller => 'questions', :action => 'show'
```

Make sure you put this *before* the default routes at the bottom of that file.  Or, even better, comment them out if you're using named routes and resources (as suggested in the auto-generated comments).

Answer (score 1):

map.resources :questions
map.friendly 'questions/:id/:title', :controller => 'questions', :action => 'show'

These are my final customizations. Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow ignores the string second parameter at request processing time. At URL construction time it adds it for humans and (probably) SEO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at the capabilities of something like [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id/) and see if those aren't what you're looking for...